# Wix Burn Bootstrapper | Identify pass\fail status of msi in chain Elemnt

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn

i have 3 MSI in my chain element i have to find which MSI pass\fails while installation so that i can i can update my table (which is in next page) with pass\fail status of MSI .

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a similar issue - I did not find any solution in the WIX framework so in the end I've just parsed the log file of the bootstrapper.

I've searched the log for lines that had the following text: "Applied execute package: " and extracted from there the exit code and the MSI name.